# Why do I get 'Error in `[.data.frame`(m, xvars) : undefined columns selected' when I run knn3() for a classification problem with ordinal variables?

Tags: r, classification, knn, categorical-data, ordinal-classification

I need to solve a classification using `knn3()`, package `caret`, from a data of airline service quality rate which is ordinal data ranging from 1-5 and categorical data like types of flying class like eco, business and eco plus. The target variable is satisfied or dissatisfied. I used model.matrix() to convert the categorical data to dummy variables and when I use the new dataset with the dummies, it gives me:

> Error in `[.data.frame`(m, xvars) : undefined columns selected.

When I fit the original dataframe, the prediction of the knn model is wrong (it gave me decimals instead of 0 or 1 for satisfied and dissatisfied).

[original data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7YlNC.png)
[head of original data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HAlWc.png)

This is how I transformed the data:
[transforming data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uSEic.png)
[transformed data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bRC36.png)

When i fit in the knn3() function, this happens:
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BKkHt.png)

Comment: Images are not a good way for posting data (or code). See [this Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/8245406) and a [relevant xkcd](https://xkcd.com/2116/). Can you post sample data in `dput` format? Please edit the question with the code you tried and with the output of `dput(data_sample)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(data_sample, 20))`.